# Package webkitgtk-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: c++, webkit, gtk, pkg-config

I received the error

> Package webkitgtk-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path

when running

```
pkg-config webkitgtk-3.0 --cflags --libs
```

in terminal. I followed the instructions from http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk and everything was a success. I even managed to launch

```
./run-launcher --gtk
```

from `Tools/Scripts/`.

How do I set the path or pkg-config to use webkit in C++?

Comment: Did you install it to the default path or did you specify a local, user-specific path for the install?

Comment: There wasn't a make file in the directory I was in. So I don't know how to run an install after the build-webkit --gtk command

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check which version of WebKitGTK+ you have installed:

- series 2.4.* provide both [WebKit1](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/index.html) and [WebKit2](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/index.html) APIs;
- series 2.6.* only provide the [WebKit2](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/index.html) API (cf [annoucement](http://webkitgtk.org/2014/09/24/webkitgtk2.6.0-released.html)).

The pkgconfig package `webkitgtk-3.0` is provided by the [WebKit1](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/index.html) API, so you need to:

- either downgrade WebKitGTK+ to 2.4.* ;
- or update the program you're building to depend on `webkit2gtk-4.0` pkgconfig package (and use the [WebKit2](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/index.html) API).

Comment: i decided to use apt-get to install it. problem solved